# Get Rails route URL in AngularJS route config

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm trying to integrate Angular routing in a Rails application.  To keep things DRY and to prevent problems if routes change as the application is developed, I'd like to prevent hard-coding the URL in the `when` property of the `$routeProvider`.   My angular files are `.js.coffee.erb` scripts to allow coffee and erb parsing.

Note: `client_views` is just a controller that renders out the `params[:id]` property, works just fine.

Example:

```
angular.module('Scheduler', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', ($rp, $lp) ->
  $rp.when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/client_views/index/'
  })
  .when('/employees/new/', {
    templateUrl : '/client_views/employee_new/  '
  })
  $lp.html5Mode(true)
  @
])
```

Ideally, I'd like to have something like:

```
angular.module('Scheduler', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', ($rp, $lp) ->
  $rp.when('/', {
    templateUrl : '<%= some_rails_url_fn :controller => "client_views", :action => "index" %>'
  })
  .when('/employees/new/', {
    templateUrl : '<%= some_rails_url_fn :controller => "employee", :action => "new" %>'
  })
  $lp.html5Mode(true)
  @
])
```

I saw the `url_for` method, but it's apparently deprecated (I'm using Rails 4), and it threw an undefined method error.

In addition, is this the correct way to use Angular routing in a Rails app?  routes.rb:

```
Scheduler::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"

  # Routes to current page
  match '/', :to => 'home#index', via: [:get]
end
```

I have a feeling that the redirect to "home#index" will break at some point...

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` is not deprecated, it's just not accessible as a helper in the context of precompiling assets. You could get access to the url helpers by specifically referencing them.

```coffee
<% url = Scheduler::Application.routes.url_helpers %>

angular.module("Scheduler", ["ngRoute"]).config [ "$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", ($rp, $lp) ->

  $rp.when "/",
    templateUrl : "<%= url.url_for controller: :client_views, action: :index %>"

  .when "/employees/new/",
    templateUrl : "<%= url.url_for controller: :employee, action: :new %>"

   $lp.html5Mode(true)
   this
]
```